# Handling errors from forms - Node / Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express

How can i go about handling errors from null form inputs or unavailable cities from weather api?
When an empty query or mispelled city is entered, the server returns errors and stops.

```
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  let cityName = req.query.city;
  let url = "";

  if (cityName == null) {
    url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=los+angeles&units=imperial&appid=${apiKey}`;
  } else {
    url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${cityName}&units=imperial&appid=${apiKey}`;
  }

  request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    data = JSON.parse(body);

    let weather = {
      city: data.name,
      temp: Math.floor(data.main.temp),
      desc: data.weather[0].description
    };

    var weather_data = { weather: weather };
    res.render("index", weather_data);
  });
});
```

displaying data with .ejs

```
<p><%= weather.city %></p>
<p><%= weather.temp %></p>
<p><%= weather.desc %></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

For handling null values you can apply form validation on forms and check var_name===null or not on backend. 
You can also check for the variable is empty string or not and u can also check it's datatype using typeof property.

For validating cities you have to save some reference of cities for which weather is available or not. For keeping app static u can store city values in array or a map and check the city when the route is accessed. If city matches then perform operations else return throw error. If u need dynamic node app use database to store cities and verify cities from there.

Also try using res.send() and res.json() to send json data instead of render.

Answer (score 0):

I think you still want to show the user something in those cases, so you want to provide something to the render regardless. If there is a genuine error, not just a 404 response, you'll probably want to set up error logging for those. When it returns not found because they requested a non-existent city, you can send back a message like 'city not found' so they know to try a different input.

Something like this provides the `weather_data` object to your client, even if it's not really weather data, to let the client know what's going on while handling things as needed on the back end.

```
    request(url, function(error, response, body) {
        data = JSON.parse(body);
        if (error) {
            // TODO: log this error somewhere
            let weather = {
                city: 'something went wrong',
                temp: '',
                desc: ''
            }
        } else if (response.statusCode === 200){
            let weather = {
                city: data.name,
                temp: Math.floor(data.main.temp),
                desc: data.weather[0].description
            };
        } else if (response.statusCode === 404){
            let weather = {
                city: 'city not found',
                temp: '',
                desc: ''
            };
        }
        var weather_data = { weather: weather };
        res.render("index", weather_data);
    });
```

Comment: When no string is entered the page just loads forever "waiting to localhost.." and never displays "something went wrong". But the code 404 does work.

Comment: Where you check if cityName is null, to provide the default url that uses LA (if that's what you want to do) try also checking if the cityName has any length: `if (cityName.length < 1 || cityName == null)`

Comment: or `if (cityName.length < 1)`, pass a message back to the front end in your `weather` object, with res.render. Depends some on what experience you want to create for your user. When they don't give a city name, what do you want to happen? Provide that response from your API.